# All of my Firefox extensions were spontaneously and simultaneously disabled

Tags: firefox

This happened a bit ago and I found the one topic with the similar name but I can not comment or reply there as it essentially seems to have been locked for additional posting and remarks or I have not posted enough yet.

Regardless this has just happened to my Firefox v48.0.2 on my primary work machine and while it hasn't happened yet on my laptop which is running v66.0.3, I am concerned and not sure if things have been fixed yet on Firefox end or not and if I will end up experiencing this on that machine also as others seemed to have mentioned in the other topic.

my base question is how can I at least re-enable them in v48.0.2"

I have tried the xpinstall.signatures.required resting it to false but it still has not re-enabled them.

Any real suggestions or input as to what I can do is appreciated and also any input as to maybe follow whats happening on the Firefox side to see their progress on fixing this.

I can not really upgrade my OS on the main workhorse machine easily as there are many things that have to be converted and updated application wise and soem are well just no longer available properly to do the job that machine does for me atm.

TIA

Comment: The question was not answered there actually and yes this is a semi duplicate bit as that is a topic I can not post in atm thus showing it was happening to other versions of Frefox and removing the extensions and trying to replace them/reinstall is not working either atm.

Comment: And an update t has now happened on my laptop with Firefox v66.0.3!!! Something definitely screwy with Firefox and its extensions verification or update checking services.

Comment: I had the same problem; the linked dupe had an answer that worked for me.  I had to try multiple things before I found one that worked with my configuration, though.